# How to extract the accepted and the top voted answer of a question from SEDE?

Tags: sql, stackexchange-api

I am writing a query to extract questions and answers from Stack Overflow [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1137469) using the following query:

```
SELECT Top 2 
q.id, q.Title, q.Body q_body, q.parentid qpid, q.AcceptedAnswerId, q.Score q_score, q.AnswerCount, q.Tags, q.viewcount,

answers.parentid aa_pid, answers.id aa_id,
answers.body aa_body, answers.score as aa_score, answers.posttypeid 

FROM 
  Posts answers

INNER JOIN Posts q 
  ON answers.parentid = q.id

WHERE (answers.id = q.AcceptedAnswerId) AND q.AnswerCount > 2
```

But, along with **accepted answer**, I also want to extract the **most voted** answer. Since, I can not even understand why **answers** is not a table.

Comment: Please check https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1145387/extract-accepted-and-most-voted-answer-of-a-question. It doesn't extract the question and it extracts only the accepted answer if it is the most voted one. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1145387) a query I came up with and you can see it live:

```
SELECT Id AS [Post Link], Body, Score
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 Id, Body, Score, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Score DESC) Rank 
    FROM (
        SELECT p.Id, p.ParentId, p.Body, p.Score
        FROM Posts p 
        WHERE p.ParentId = ##QuestionId##
    )x
    ORDER BY Rank ASC
)x

UNION
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT Id, Body, Score
    FROM (
        SELECT a.Id, a.ParentId, a.Body, a.Score FROM Posts a 
        WHERE a.ParentId = ##QuestionId##
    )x
)x 
WHERE (SELECT b.AcceptedAnswerId FROM Posts b WHERE b.id = ##QuestionId##) = id
```

The first piece finds the top voted answer, while the second one searches for the accepted answer (if there's one).

Both are a bit complicated because `Posts` table is about answers as well as questions. This is the reason for the two nested `FROM`s.